# Can mold be leaking through pipes cracks/holes?

Tags: pipe, mold

I know that mold is definetely leaking through some of the deep holes in my flat.  You can see brick in the holes as well as space for air to travel.

1. Can pipes with cracks and holes behind them also leak contaminated air?  I'm not sure what exactly surrounds the inner wall where pipes are passing but if its the same as deep holes then I guess it can.
2. When filling can you go right up to the pipe and make it airtight?  in some builds I notice there is a small seemingly deliberate gap but if there were a leak above that would not be visible.

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Most of what people call "mold" in such situations is actually "lime" -- water seepage that has evaporated and left behind dissolved minerals.  To tell the difference, try rubbing with vinegar --lime will dissolve in the vinegar but mold will no. (Whereas bleach will remove mold but not lime.)

Answer (score 1):

The pipe connected to the radiator has a deliberate space because it is really hot.
Can air leak through walls that has mold? Don’t want to scare you but just about every breath you take may have a mold or fungus spores, in the Forrest 100%  In  most living spaces.
Can you seal the pipes, I mentioned the radiator but there are special collars made to insulate and seal these, water pipes usually can be foamed to seal them. Make sure you know what you are sealing and use the proper material.

Answer (score 0):

You must fix the leak first, or you will never get rid of the mold. Mold spores are everywhere, you cannot avoid them. To grow they need moisture (air flow can dry it and help prevent mold), food and a surface to grown on. Check this link for more information. https://www.environix.com/mold/learning/basement-mold/mold-on-concrete/